# Per-Vertex lighting in GLSL?

Tags: rendering, game-engine, 3d-view, light, opengl

How can I achieve per-vertex lighting (like in single/multi-texture shading) in GLSL with all of the other GLSL features (like buffer shadows, texture layers, etc.)? Bonus points if it can be done in the viewport.

I could bake the lights to v-cols but that is not realtime and I don't get any of the GLSL features (or hemi lamps for the matter) with single/multi-texture shading.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. You'd have to write your own GLSL vertex/frag shader to simulate a per-vertex lighting. But then, you lose the ability take advantage of the Blender material system.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this tutorial from Blender Cookie do what you're looking for? http://cgcookie.com/blender/2014/06/17/realtime-glsl-lighting-shading/

Comment: Could you light everything like normal but change the shading type to *tangent shading*? I don't know much about per-vertex lighting, but if it just makes the lighting look a different way as per normal, then you could go to the *Materials Tab* and under the *Shading* header, tick the boxes for *Tangent Shading* and *Cubic Interpolation*?

Comment: I think this would probably require [custom blender code](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Contents), it probably hasn't been developed due to the lack of need.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: could you Instance a lamp to each one of the vertices?